# Combining logical operators

Tags: boolean, logical-operators

I have an expression of the form

```
A or A and B
```

Can we represent it more concisely by representing the expression some other way?

Comment: Try creating a truth table and see what you get.

Comment: That is a good idea

Comment: Is `A or A and B` equal to `A or (A and B)` or `(A or A) and B`? Presumably the former, though there is no universally agreed upon precedence for logical operators. In any event: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_law

Comment: @CollinD the truth table gives A as the representation. If A is 1 the 1 else 0. Interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated the expression may be slightly ambiguous. It can be interpereted in two ways:

```
(A or A) and B
```

Obviously `A or A` is logically equivalent to `A`, so in this case the entire statement is simply equivalent to `A and B`

More likely, this is intended to be read as

```
A or (A and B)
```

Let's write a truth table for this

```
A B | A or (A and B) | result
-----------------------------
0 0 | 0 or (0 and 0) | 0
0 1 | 0 or (0 and 1) | 0
1 0 | 1 or (1 and 0) | 1
1 1 | 1 or (1 and 1) | 1
```

Now you can pretty clearly see, in this case the statement is equivalent to `A` alone.